# Phrase to means "something a hipster would like"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

I've been trying to come up with a phrase that means "something a hipster would like" in the modern context. *Cool* and *hip* seem kind of dated, so what would be a good recommendation for a more modern phrase (that a hipster would use?)

Downvotes only make this hipster post more valid!

Comment: Are you looking for "avant-garde"?

Comment: I might say that about the things that hipsters like, but would they?  I would also say cool and awesome, but I'm not much of a hipster.

Comment: What age Hipster do you have in mind?

Comment: A hipster would use old terms because the term hipster is old.

Comment: If there are different phrases used by different age groups, I'd live to see them all.

Comment: I'd tell you all about how to describe the things a hipster likes, but you've probably never heard of them.

Comment: On a more serious note: downvotes?

Comment: Downvotes only make this hipster post more valid!

Comment: Upvoted to counter the downvotes - don't see why this question deserves them.

Comment: @Hoytman, when you say "hipster", do you mean the stereotype of someone who does everything that other people don't do, trying to go against the mainstream, etc.? Or are you referring to someone who we would have described as "cool" or "hip" - if, as you say, those words weren't so dated?

Comment: Actually, this is for a product design: Grow your own seaweed (Nori) at home.  The target market includes this group:  Young professions who are health conscious, environmentally conscious, open to or actively perusing non-mainstream activities and very aware of emerging trends.  I though 'hipster', but now I see that this may be a negative term.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, *cutting edge* or *bleeding edge*. It seems like hipsters like a lot of [*indie*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=indie) (independent movies, music, etc.) stuff too, even though the word itself doesn't necessarily convey that something is hipster.

Why did the hipster burn his tongue? Because he tried drinking coffee before it was cool.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use "trendy"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We expect answers to provide explanations, linked to appropriate references; it would be good to explain *why* you would use *trendy* here— "hipsters" are usually dying to prove they do whatever is *not* trendy. I would also encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and peruse the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to contribute to this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest "hipsterish".

"Hipsterish" isn't really a word, but since "hipster" is pretty slang anyway, I think you would get away with it. Plus I'm assuming you are looking for something a little tongue in cheek. If this is for an academic paper on the preferences of hipsters, you'll probably want something different.

Comment: Actually, this is a term for marketing, and I'm guessing I should drop the term hipster all together.

Answer (score 1):

With the angle of what a hipster would actually use, you have to approach it from a (vaguely) positive sense. Personally knowing a good deal of hipsters and budding hipsters personally (you've probably never heard of them), the terms I hear used the most are

- *Undiscovered*: Not exactly praise, but it does give the idea that they can be *discovered*. (Interestingly enough, once something is *discovered*, they tend to stop talking about it)
- *Unappreciated*: Gives a sense of superiority, as if they know something that nobody else can see.
- *Underappreciated*: Used less often than *unappreciated*, because it gives the sense that the subject is appreciated somewhat in general.

Answer (score 1):

How about "That's hot!"?

> [that's hot](http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%27s+hot&page=2): expression popularized by Paris Hilton. Frequently used by hipsters who should know better but are desperate to sound cool and cutting edge hip.

Alternately, consider *sick* and *dope*.

> [sick](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sick&page=2): *sl.* usually used in the US when something is cool or exciting
>
> [dope](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dope): *sl.* great or excellent -- used as a generalized term of approval

Answer (score 1):

Hipsters hate everything **mainstream**; what they like is **offbeat**.